# Nautilus doesn' allow thumbnail for image size above 4096 KiB

Tags: gnome, nautilus, 18.10, thumbnails

In Ubuntu 18.10, Nautilus doesn't allow thumbnail size for image above 4096KiB.
In preference pane, it is not possible to increase value above 4096.

This is a regression, because it was possible before. By the way, whatever the value of dconf property `org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/thumbnail-limit`, if it is above 4096, Nautilus will not observe it.
Setting the max image size for thumbnail generation in Nautilus preference pane  is correctly changing `org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/thumbnail-limit`.

Other funny things : the default value for `org/gnome/nautilus/preferences/thumbnail-limit` is 10MiB, so if it is at default value, Nautilus is showing (and observing) its hard-coded max of "4096" (4MiB) !

Is it possible to workaround this regression ?

Comment: FYI The same limit exists in Nautilus from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. But for example Caja (Nautilus fork) allows any value (dropdown menu ends in 4 GB margin even in Ubuntu MATE 19.04).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No workaround found, upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04 solved the issue.
I successfully tested 8MiB and 10MiB thumbnail size limit using Nautilus preference pane.

Answer (score 1):

After upgrading to 19.04 (coming all the way from 16.04), I found that the value was set to "4096 **MB**", which seems to be a weird bug. After pasting "10 MiB" in the text field, everything worked fine and I could raise the value as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround is: installing gthumb, ($sudo apt install gthumb)
a more professional image viewer, and very useful.
I tested it can preview at least +5M JPG.
HIH